# Problem with TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am having an odd behavior of the contents - The Chapteps/sections keep getting incremental values , like in the attached pictures. Also, I would like it to be

Chapter 1
1.1 ....
1.2 ....

rather than it is now

I am using

```
![\setcounter{totalnumber}{10}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{blindtext}][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf starting on page 13

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial impression is you are "skipping" one category of your class.

For example, the hierarchy of the `report` class goes:

`\chapter`

`\section`

`\subsection`

`\subsubsection`

If you use a `subsection` before a `section` then it is assumed to be 0.