# How to make different command for subparagraph (or any other sectioning) with empty and nonempty title?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I want to make a sectioning command (for example subparagraph) that will have a different behavior for command with empty title.

This is my MWE, showing somewhat about i want to get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7} 

\makeatletter    
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subparagraph{Subparagraph with title}

Some random text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\subparagraph{} Some random text for subparagraph without title

\end{document}
```

I looked at the answer for this question: [\section with empty title. Show number next to first paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232187/section-with-empty-title-show-number-next-to-first-paragraph)

It does the same thing as I want, but can I get the same result without `titlesec`?

Comment: *Without* titlesec? But you didn't load it.

Comment: @Bernard Edited the mistake in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `\subparagraph{}` isn't the normal way of using LaTeX's `\subparagraph` command, so it may be a good idea to give your command a different name. I am going to answer with the `\subparagraph` name anyway, as it is what was asked in the question. I propose two methods, both using `xparse` in order to easily grab and analyze all possible arguments of `\subparagraph` (with or without star, with or without the optional argument inside square brackets).

## Using `xparse` and `etoolbox` (“LaTeX2e style”)

This method uses `xparse` and `etoolbox`. Additionally, it exploits the fact that `\@startsection`'s fifth argument will necessarily be expanded when TeX uses it. If you want a blank mandatory argument of your `\subparagraph` to be handled the same way as an empty one, just replace `\ifstrempty` with `\ifblank`; then, `\subparagraph{    }` and `\subparagraph{}` will have same behavior.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\alecheim@subparagraph}[1]{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    % The following argument will be expanded during <glue> assignments
    {\ifstrempty{#1}{-1em}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subparagraph}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\alecheim@subparagraph{#3}*{#3}}
    {\alecheim@subparagraph{#3}[#2]{#3}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subparagraph{Subparagraph with title}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\subparagraph{} Some random text for subparagraph without title.

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

## Using `xparse` and `expl3` (“`expl3` style”)

The following method uses techniques from `expl3`, the language from the LaTeX3 project. It *could* but doesn't rely on the fact that the fifth argument of `\@startsection` will automatically be expanded at some point; instead, we do the required expansion ourselves in the following line, which stores the result in `\l_tmpa_tl`:

```latex
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_if_empty:nTF {#3} { -1em } { 1.5ex \@plus .2ex } }
```

Then we use a `V` argument type with `\alecheim_subparagraph:V \l_tmpa_tl` in order to pass `\alecheim_subparagraph:n` the *value* of `\l_tmpa_tl`. Here is the full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \alecheim_subparagraph:n #1
  {
    \@startsection { subparagraph } { 5 } { \parindent }
      { 3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex }
      {#1}
      { \normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \alecheim_subparagraph:n { V }

\RenewDocumentCommand { \subparagraph } { s O{#3} m }
  {
    % You may want to replace \tl_if_empty:nTF with \tl_if_blank:nTF here.
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_if_empty:nTF {#3} { -1em } { 1.5ex \@plus .2ex } }
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \alecheim_subparagraph:V \l_tmpa_tl * {#3} }
      { \alecheim_subparagraph:V \l_tmpa_tl [#2]{#3} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subparagraph{Subparagraph with title}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\subparagraph{} Some random text for subparagraph without title.

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.